# Implementing Google Analytics on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I am looking for guidance on how to add Google Analytics to my ArcGIS for Server implementation (I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Server, and planning to migrate to ArcGIS 10.3 soon).

Comment: Google analytics will not give specific arcserver analytics (only [if your web server is exclusively used for web mapping] each page visit can have metrics to be used). Go to google analytics to implement. It is simple, paste a 1 line code in your web page and walla it starts collecting metrics. Then you have to actually use GA to sort, measure, parse, and analyze all the great data.

Comment: my bad, GA has changed since I used it last. now apparently you host it on your own web server. Just go to github. It is all open source. https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools

Comment: @BradNesom I think you should write this up as an answer of a few sentences.